# Objective C - Random plist string to NSString instead displays (null)

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, plist

I am trying to display a random plist string but when I NSLog it all that displays is '(null)' perhaps I did something wrong in the code:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:

                  @"small" ofType:@"plist"];



NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSMutableArray *plistArray = plistDict[@"Value"];

NSInteger randV = arc4random_uniform(plistArray.count); // randV is from 0 to number of strings -1 in array

[super viewDidLoad];

self.correctWord = [plistArray objectAtIndex:randV];

[self setupHangmanWord:self.correctWord];
}
```

and this is my small.plist file:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND8bY.jpg)

any help would be awesome.. Thanks

Comment: Check if the `plistDict` variable is non-nil. If it's `nil`, it means your `path` is incorrect.

Comment: Yep, dollars to donuts plistDict is nil.  And if not plistDict then plistArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
NSMutableArray *plistArray = plistDict[@"Value"];
```

The property list you show a screenshot of has an array as the root object.  This line of code assumes that it is a dictionary with a key of `Value`.

You've got an extra step in here you don't need.  You're trying to fetch an array out of a dictionary, but you're starting with the array and you don't have a dictionary.

You should use this:

```
NSArray *plistArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: But if `plistDict` were in fact an array then `plistDict[@"Value"]` would crash.

Comment: So what should I do instead of NSMutableArray *plistArray = plistDict[@"Value"];
?

Comment: You don't need it.  Delete it.  That gets an array out of a dictionary, but there's no dictionary - you're getting the array directly from the property list.

Comment: @MartinR, that's true.  I suspect it's a combination of both problems - superfluous dictionary code and the file is not present at that path.  That would mean that he's getting `nil`, which would mask the crash that would occur if he were actually loading the property list properly.